# SVG File With Dynamic Fill Colors - Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, vue-component, vuejs3

I am making a twitter clone application with VueJS 3.

I saved Twitter's logo as a .svg file and can use it with the `<img />` tag. I can also change its color when I give the `<svg>` tag the `fill="#fff"` attribute. However, I want to use this .svg file in multiple places and in different colors.

So I tried to dynamically change the color of the svg by giving the `<img />` tag the classes `fill-white`, `bg-white` and `text-white`, but it didn't work.

**My Currently .svg File - With White Color**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
    <g>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M23.643 4.937c-... 1.7-1.477 2.323-2.41z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Img Tag**

```html
<img
 src="/twitter-bird.svg"
 draggable="false"
 class="w-52 lg:w-96 fill-white"
 alt="Twitter Bird"
/>
```

**I Tried This On .svg File**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
    <g>
        <path fill="params(fill) #fff" d="M23.643 4.937c-... 1.7-1.477 2.323-2.41z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I understand that I need to make this svg's color editable. But I couldn't find how to do this.

Comment: Tried `:fill="my-prop-color"`  (without tw)?

Comment: Yes I tried passing the fill props as well. It didn't make sense as the place I sent the props to was not the .vue file, but I tried it anyway. Like `fill="#fff"`

Comment: "I saved Twitter's logo as a .svg file and can use it with the <img />" If svg was changed to a Vue component instead then having dynamic colors should be easy.

Comment: Oh, thank you... I create svg .vue component and i did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make component from svg file and bind fill to prop:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      colors: ['#8A2BE2', 'rgb(255,255,0)', '#008000'],
    };
  },
})
app.component('myImg', {
  template: `
    <svg height="40" viewBox="0 0 107.1 107.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 107.1 107.1;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path :fill="color" d="M2.287,47.815l23.096,19.578L18.2,96.831c-1.411,5.491,4.648,9.998,9.575,6.901L53.55,87.813l25.774,15.916   c4.79,2.955,10.844-1.408,9.576-6.902l-7.184-29.435l23.099-19.579c4.363-3.661,2.111-10.844-3.662-11.267l-30.282-2.255   L59.464,6.266c-2.112-5.211-9.577-5.211-11.832,0L36.225,34.292L5.944,36.547C0.174,37.113-2.081,44.154,2.287,47.815z"/>
  </svg>
  `,
  props: ['color']
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="col in colors">
    <my-img :color="col"></my-img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      colors: ['#8A2BE2', 'rgb(255,255,0)', '#008000'],
    };
  },
})
app.component('myImg', {
  template: `
    <svg height="40" viewBox="0 0 107.1 107.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 107.1 107.1;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path :fill="color" d="M2.287,47.815l23.096,19.578L18.2,96.831c-1.411,5.491,4.648,9.998,9.575,6.901L53.55,87.813l25.774,15.916   c4.79,2.955,10.844-1.408,9.576-6.902l-7.184-29.435l23.099-19.579c4.363-3.661,2.111-10.844-3.662-11.267l-30.282-2.255   L59.464,6.266c-2.112-5.211-9.577-5.211-11.832,0L36.225,34.292L5.944,36.547C0.174,37.113-2.081,44.154,2.287,47.815z"/>
  </svg>
  `,
  props: ['color']
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="col in colors">
    <my-img :color="col"></my-img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks very similar to the answer that was posted 3 weeks ago.